# Wrapper for NSLog

Tags: objective-c, macros, nslog

I have seen examples on wrapping NSLog but am not 100% sure on the details.

e.g. `#define debugLog(fmt,...) NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__]);`

What exactly are the arguments here?

If I wanted to add a constant string to a log such as

```
- (void) logMessage:(NSString *) message ofType:(NSString *) type
{

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", type, message);
}
```

how would I create this in a #define macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debugLog` is a variadic macro (one that takes a variable number of arguments). The particular macro calls `NSLog` with 2 arguments, the first being a format string (`@"%@"`), and the second being an autoreleased string returned by `stringWithFormat` which takes the passed format string plus the variadic arguments of the macro.

`__VA_ARGS__` is the way to refer to the variable argument list within the macro. It corresponds to the `...` in the parameter list.

Instead of your `logMessage` method, you could use the `debugLog` macro to achieve the same result:

```
debugLog("%@ - %@", type, message);
```

The macro itself seems a bit pointless though, since it is only wrapping `NSLog` without adding anything else.

If you want a macro that corresponds directly to `logMessage`, then you don't have to deal with a variadic list at all:

```
#define logMessageAsMacro(message, type) NSLog(@"%@ - %@", message, type)
```

You'll have to be careful about whether both of the arguments are `NSString`'s, since macros are type-unsafe.

Comment: Thanks, could you suggest how to write the logMessage method above into a macro?

Comment: Thanks a lot. do I define this in the prefix file?

Comment: You could define it anywhere you consider logical in your project.

Comment: I am trying to pass in an NSString stringWithFormat with 1 argument as the first argument to the macro and a second NSString as the 2nd argument to the macro, but I says there are too many args provided. Does the argument of the NSString stringWithFormat in the first arg get counted as a arg? here is the line logMessageAsMacro([NSString stringWithFormat:@"some string with arg %@", arg], TESTLOG);